# Creating a self-filtering AngularJS resultset

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I've created my jsfiddle here for reference:
[http://jsfiddle.net/7gzDG/](http://jsfiddle.net/xYMVL/)

```
 $scope.list = [{
        "Colors": ["Blue", "Eggplant", "Green", "Pink", "Yellow"],
            "Brand": "BRAND A",
            "Name": "Item 1"
    }, {
        "Colors": ["Black", "Dark Teal", "Eggplant"],
            "Brand": "BRAND A",
            "Name": "Item 2"
    }, {
        "Colors": ["Ivory", "Pink"],
            "Brand": "BRAND A",
            "Name": "Item 3"
    }, {
        "Colors": ["Black", "Brown", "Red", "White"],
            "Brand": "BRAND B",
            "Name": "Item 4"
    }];
```

Above my products have

1. an array of colors
2. a specific brand

I can build the distinct list of each as checkboxes.

```
myApp.filter('uniqueColors', function () {
    return function (list) {
        var colors = {};
        angular.forEach(list, function (obj) {
            angular.forEach(obj.Colors, function (color) {
                colors[color] = color;
            })
        });
        //console.log(colors);
        var uniqueColors = []
        for (var key in colors) {
            uniqueColors.push(key);
        }
        return uniqueColors;
    }
});

myApp.filter('uniqueBrands', function () {
    return function (list) {
        var brands = {};
        angular.forEach(list, function (obj) {
            brands[obj.Brand] = obj.Brand;
        });
        //console.log(brands);
        var uniqueBrands = []
        for (var key in brands) {
            uniqueBrands.push(key);
        }
        return uniqueBrands.sort();
    }
});
```

My issue is that I'm unable to figure out how to, when I check them, filter the original resultset.  For instance, if I check "Blue" I want all products with the color Blue to remain.

If I check Blue and Red, I want all product with Blue OR Red to remain.

If I check Blue and Red with Brand A, I want all products that are Brand A to have Blue OR Red in them.

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you looking for, but I created another filter for products.

http://jsfiddle.net/btcxV/3/

```
myApp.filter('filterProduct', function() {
return function(list, colorFilter, brandFilter) {
    var products = [];

    if((Object.keys(colorFilter).length == 0) && (Object.keys(brandFilter).length == 0))
        return list;

    angular.forEach(list, function(product) {  

      angular.forEach(product.Colors, function(color) {  

        if(colorFilter[color])
            products.push(product);
      });
      angular.forEach(product.Brands, function(brand) {  

        if(brandFilter[color])
            products.push(product);
      });            

    });

    return products;
}
```

});

Comment: Looks good... brands isn't working (missing ng-model?)
it's definitely one step closer to a functional prototype

Comment: Yes, there was a few mistakes... This seems to be working. http://jsfiddle.net/btcxV/3/